# R2WinBugs data entry incompatible copy error for Conditional Binomial likelihood, probit link, Random Effects (Psoriasis example)

Tags: syntax-error, logistic-regression, bayesian-networks, r2winbugs, random-effects

I was working on the the guide for calculating the effect size of different treatments using a NETWORK META-ANALYSIS as done in example 6.a.
[Here](http://mdm.sagepub.com/content/suppl/2012/10/26/0272989X12458724.DC1/DS_10.1177_0272989X12458724.pdf)

It works fine in winBugs, but I want to do the analysis in R using R2winugs so that I can automate the data input.

It reads the model just fine according to the log, but it gets hung up when reading the data.

E.G.
display(log)
check(C:/Users/Temp User/.../Plaque_Psoriasis_Project/RE_Psoriasis.bug.txt)
model is syntactically correct
data(C:/Users/Temp User/.../Plaque_Psoriasis_Project/data.txt)

This is where the program just hangs. 
The trap screen reads

**incompatible copy**

BugsCmds.TextError   [000003A1H]

```
.beg    INTEGER 1699018032

.end    INTEGER 34825508
```

.......

I've tried reading the data as:

data <- list(t=t,C=C,r=r,n=n,na=na,nc=nc, ns=ns, nt=nt, Cmax=Cmax, meanA=meanA, precA=precA)

and as

data <- list("t","C","r","n","na","nc", "ns", "nt", "Cmax", "meanA", "precA")

Neither works.

I got R2winbugs to do the toy school example in the documentation so it can work.

Any thoughts?